# Displaying score result in another activity

Tags: android, textview

[image]
How can I display the score result in an activity from another activity? I have here my MainActivity and ScoreActivity. I want to display the score in ScoreActivity from MainActivity's TextView. Is it possible? How can I achieve that?

**MainActivity**

```js
//COUNTDOOWNTIMER
public void onFinish() {
   // TODO Auto-generated method stub
   timer.setText("Time's Up!");
   topScore.setText(score.getText());//the textview for best score
   run();//to store the value in topScore
   
   Intent i = new Intent("app.thesis.boggleit.TOPSCORE");
   startActivity(i); //themedActivity
   
   Intent score = new Intent(MainActivity.this, TopScore.class);
   score.putExtra("scores", topScore.getText().toString());
   
   }
```

**TopScore**

```js
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class TopScore extends Activity{

 TextView topscore;
 
 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.top_score);
  
  topscore = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvNewTScore);
  
  String scores = getIntent().getStringExtra("scores");
  topscore.setText(scores);
  
 }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In main activity:

```
public void onFinish() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        timer.setText("Time's Up!");
        topScore.setText(score.getText());//the textview for best score
        run();//to store the value in topScore

        Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this,ScoreActivity.class);
        i.putExtra("scores", topScore.getText().toString());

        startActivity(i); //themedActivity
}
```

In score:

```
String scores = getIntent().getStringExtra("scores");
```

Answer (score 1):

In your intent message object, add a bundle and save your score value.

In Score Activity, retrieve the value from the bundle.

In MainActivity :

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setClass(this, Score_Activity.class);
intent.putExtra("EXTRA_ID", "Score Value");
startActivity(intent);
```

In Score_Activity :

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
  if (extras != null) {
   String datas= extras.getString("EXTRA_ID");
   if (datas!= null) {
        // do stuff
   }        
}
```

Comment: Hi :)Can you explain it further? I updated my question above. Please take a look at it. @Prem

Comment: @LabLey, After this line of code,startActivity(i);, next 2 lines will not be executed. Your question is not clear. Why you are running in onFinish method ? Do you want to run a thread and based on result, update a textview in different class ?

Comment: I have it running in onFinish method because in my game, the score saves after the time is over and this TopScore Activity(theme.dialog) will be showing the score the player got.